# Angular Router: Navigating to previous route escapes characters

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I´m currently in the work of creating a simple back-button through creating a routing-history. Every time the user navigates to a new route, I store the current url before finishing the navigation in an array such like:

```js
  public routeHistory: string[] = [];

  ...
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
     this.routeHistory.push(event.url);
  }
  ...
```

Then I created a method to navigate to the previous route:

```js
  public navigateBack(): void {
    // If there is a previous route
    if (this.routeHistory.length > 1) {
      const previousRoute: string = this.routeHistory[this.routeHistory.length - 2];

      this.router.navigate([previousRoute]).then(result => {
        // If navigation was successful
        if (result) {
          this.routeHistory.pop();
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Everything works perfectly until the previousRoute contains parameters such as `/route;param=value` because the `router.navigate` method escapes '/' and '=' leading to the router navigating to `/route%3Bparam%3Dvalue`.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried `router.navigateByUrl(url)` ?

Comment: @AndreiGătej Thank you, it seems to work as intended with ``router.navigateByUrl(url)``. I though navigateByUrl would only work with absolute urls.

Comment: You’re welcome! It works with any URLs, prepending ‘/‘ will make it an absolute URL. Mind if I add it as an answer?

Comment: No, post the answer, I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with `router.navigateByUrl(url)`.